# Load External Custom Page and Execute Custom CSS or Javascript on The page

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

i'm building an online document portal that supports all Microsoft Office formats.
Instead of building my own module, i'm utilizing Google Docs Online Viewer since it already handles
this task properly, my only problem is it loads the header toolbar, which i dont want.

take for example This custom pdf-URL(i just googled for any pdf document), The navigation toolbar at the foot, but the header toobar, i want it hidden - all within the iFrame.

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.scorpioncomputerservices.com/Press%20Coverage/Billgates.doc&embedded=false&controls=false
```

[image]

After Inspecting the Element on Chrome, i found the section of code controlling the element, problem is, how to hide this element on page load, by forcing a script/style to be executed on the page, while loading.

[image]

i would like to know if there's a way i could force-delete or hide the element controlling the toolbar within the iFrame, or better still if there are any alternatives to what i intend to do. my code would have looked like this

```
var obj = iframe.document.querySelectorAll('[role="toolbar"]');
obj.parentNode.removeElement(obj);

// or - i'm not sure anyof this would work.. and since it is loaded inside an iframe 
// how do i execute this. 

obj.remove();
```

i dont want my audience to be able to download the document, obviously curious developers might find a way, but thats going to be less than 2% - 5% of the total users. 
how do i go about this please using javascript/CSS/or any library.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the GET variable `embedded` to true the viewer won't display the top bar, however there's no way to edit the page inside the iFrame as Google has enabled cross site protection so the browser will prevent you from running any javascript to modify the content of the iFrame.

The only way to use the google document viewer is to get your site to load it in the background (not using an iFrame) and modify it before serving the page to the user.

Or alternitively I reccommend using an open source JS PDF viewer such as [ViewerJS](https://viewerjs.org/)